# Restful api routes naming convention for specific filter

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions, api-design, restful-url

I have in database some "Evaluation" which have foreign key nullable to "Category"

So in standard Rest route I've done this 2 routes :

- `GET /api/categories/{category_id}/evaluations` (for a specific category)
- `GET /api/evaluations` (for all evaluations with or without category)

My question is for the GET on evaluations which DON'T have a category (named "basic" evaluation), how should I name it :

- `GET /api/evaluations/basic`
- `GET /api/basic/evaluations`
- `GET /api/categories/evaluations`
- `GET /api/categories/basic/evaluations`

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `basic` sounds like an Evaluation type, you could implement this by filtering through query string:

`GET /api/evaluations?type=basic`

This of course can also be extended to support even more filtering, as well as sorting or paging